# Why my facebook graph reporting API results cannot be breakdown by hours

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I wrote some code in googe sheet script to get ads report using FB graph API.

it works fine, but when I set the breakdown as "hourly_stats_aggregated_by_advertiser_time_zone".

It will only return basic info: spend, impression, click.

When I change the breakdown to country for example, the same code can return purchase, register etc.

Code as below:

fields listed below is :account_currency,account_id,account_name,campaign_name,impressions,clicks,outbound_clicks,spend,action_values,unique_actions,actions

```
function requestReport(accountId) {
  // Builds the Facebook Ads Insights API URL
  const facebookUrl = `https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/act_${accountId}/insights?level=${LEVEL}&breakdowns=${BREAKDOWN}&fields=${FIELDS}&filtering=[{field: 'action_type',operator:'IN', value:["omni_app_install","omni_purchase","omni_complete_registration"]}]&time_increment=1&time_range={'since':'${START_DATE}','until':'${END_DATE}'}&access_token=${TOKEN}&locale=zh_CN`;
  Logger.log(facebookUrl);
  const encodedFacebookUrl = encodeURI(facebookUrl);
  const options = {
    'method': 'post'
  };

  // Fetches & parses the URL 
  const fetchRequest = UrlFetchApp.fetch(encodedFacebookUrl, options);
  const results = JSON.parse(fetchRequest.getContentText());

  // Caches the report run ID
  const reportId = results.report_run_id;
  const cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
  const cached = cache.get('campaign-report-id');

  if (cached != null) {
    cache.put('campaign-report-id', [], 1);
    Utilities.sleep(1001);
    cache.put('campaign-report-id', reportId, 21600);
  } else {
    cache.put('campaign-report-id', reportId, 21600);
  }
  
  Logger.log(cache.get('campaign-report-id'));
  return reportId;
}
```

I tried different settings of the url, only when the breakdown is changed to hour, the whole results is limited.

I am wondering if this is the way Graph report API always is.

I wish the report can be breakdown by hour.